# Neo4j query returns different results

Tags: neo4j

Repeating a query after running a few other queries in the meantime may result in different results. This shows up only in larger databases and it was a little difficult to reproduce. However, the following protocol will almost surely (worked on windows and linux installations) show the same problem:

1. Begin with a newly created empty database.
2. Create unique index for identifying nodes when importing relationships. Wait until index is online.
3. Load many nodes from CSV.

   ```
   //load nodes from UTF-8 encoded TSV file
   USING PERIODIC COMMIT
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///all_nodes.tsv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
   MERGE (root:UID {Spec:row.UID})
   WITH root,row
   // set additional label
   CALL apoc.create.addLabels(root,[row.Label]) YIELD node AS labnode
   // set additional property
   CALL apoc.create.setProperty(root,row.PropName,row.PropValue) YIELD node as propnode
   RETURN count(*)
   ```
4. Load many relationships from CSV.

   ```
   // load relationships from UTF-8 encoded TSV file
   USING PERIODIC COMMIT
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///all_edges.tsv' AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
   MATCH (sourcenode:UID {Spec:row.SourceUID})
   MATCH (targetnode:UID {Spec:row.TargetUID})
   WITH row,sourcenode,targetnode
   CALL apoc.merge.relationship(sourcenode,row.Relationship,CASE row.PropName 
   WHEN "Source" THEN {Source:row.PropValue} ELSE {} END,{}, targetnode) YIELD rel
   RETURN count(*)
   ```
5. MATCH (n) RETURN count(*).
6. MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(*).
7. Delete many relationships until all relationships are deleted.

7.5. MATCH (n) RETURN count(*).

7.6. MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(*).

8. Load same relationships from CSV (same query as in 4).

8.5. MATCH (n) RETURN count(*).

9. MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(*).

I cannot make my data publicly available, so I can only show the numbers:

**Test Case 1:**
Loaded 5908886 nodes and 11801553 relationships.
Deleted all relationships in small batches.
Finalized with MATCH ()-[r]->() DELETE r.
Database contained 5908886 nodes and 0 relationships.
Loaded 11801871 relationships.
Database contained 5908886 nodes and 11801871 relationships.

**Test Case 2:**
Loaded 3338901 nodes and 8892829 relationships.
Deleted all relationships in small batches.
Finalized with MATCH ()-[r]->() DELETE r.
Database contained 3338901 nodes and 0 relationships.
Loaded 8893041 relationships.
Database contained 3338901 nodes and 8893041 relationships.

The differences are only 318 and 212 relationships, but should they not be 0?

EDIT: Partial solution has been found. The two above test cases contained unescaped Neo4j control characters such as / (forward slash) in the property values to be imported. APOC didn't recognize these as errors and thus they were introduced to the database store. Whenever a query was run that accessed these parameter values, it caused unexpected side effects that 'corrupted' the database. The issue has been more or less resolved by removing these faulty property values from the CSV input.

Comment: That's very strange. And if you do the counts again between 7. and 8. they do still show you the correct number of nodes and a zero for the number of relationships (so they are all deleted) ?

Comment: Can you show all your `LOAD CSV` Cypher queries? Also, did the number of nodes change after loading?